# 3d surface plot

Tags: plotting

I have a similar list:

```
list={{x1,y1,z1},...,{xn,yn,zn}]
```

I would like to build a three dimensional surface starting from this points. But If I do:

```
ListSurfacePlot3D[{{3, 3, 3.0888508535531155`*^-196}, {3, 4, 4.7909072659912834`*^-123}, {3,5,2.608990419496028`*^-77},{3, 6,3.856414490200229`*^-55},{3, 7, 2.0163491704413096`*^-50}, {3, 8,3.7688162148113437`*^-53}, {4, 3, 1.5674475737296968`*^-160}, {4, 4, 1.2781340865795685`*^-87}, {4, 5, 8.07610824215987`*^-43}, {4,6, 9.1908184109933`*^-23}, {4, 7, 2.2208730268285067`*^-22}, {4, 8,
1.947435021094519`*^-34}, {5, 3, 1.630637845554207`*^-137}, {5, 4,
2.2810665263467505`*^-65}, {5, 5, 1.8907935158785598`*^-22}, {5, 6, 0.000011447560131002648`}, {5, 7,    1.344944362543352`*^-10}, {5,8, 2.3452191942386287`*^-31}, {6, 3, 2.868906891871641`*^-124},  {6,4,1.7168646885898172`*^-53}, {6, 5, 2.7200723872630333`*^-13}, {6, 6, 1.`}, {6, 7,8.802702897446029`*^-12}, {6, 8, 2.3655511028986504`*^-41}, {7, 3, 2.768540344562032`*^-117}, {7, 4,1.3825024906819504`*^-48}, {7, 5, 6.156052775453513`*^-12}, {7, 6, 0.0001778904787899639`}, {7, 7,1.8907935158785598`*^-22}, {7, 8, 2.9880166623270176`*^-61}, {8, 3,1.702328878243957`*^-113}, {8, 4, 3.1104576718518376`*^-47}, {8, 5, 8.193450673171766`*^-15}, {8, 6, 2.717501317845451`*^-13}, {8,  7, 5.304631672177736`*^-39}, {8, 8, 1.2781340865796413`*^-87}}]
```

I can't see the surface peaked at z=1. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try ListPlot3D. ListSurfacePlot3D does some fitting between the given Points.

Comment: Thank you I solved with ListPlot3D and PlotRange->All